# Make programs binded to other network interface use other gateway than default

Tags: linux, networking

I would like for a program that binded to network interface that is not eth0 to use other default gateway when making connections.

```
ip rule add oif tun0 table 11
ip route add default via 10.3.33.20 table 11
ip route flush cache
```

```
ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all iif tun0 lookup 11
32765:  from all oif tun0 lookup 11
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
ip route list table all
default via 10.3.33.20 dev tun0 table 11
default via 172.104.159.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
10.3.0.0/16 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.33.21
172.104.159.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.104.159.249 metric 100
...
```

When I bind program to interface tun0 it does not transmit antything to gateway 10.3.33.20

Comment: If the application is bound to specific if, then hopefully you can have a IP rule on the source IP. `ip rule add from $ip table 11`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, ip rule add from <tun0-interface-ip> table 11 works while ip rule add oif tun0 table 11 for some reason wont.

Comment: If I remember correctly, interface has not yet been determined, it is only decided after routing, oif probably works on things like modifying src ip in the route.

Answer (score 0):

works:

```
ip rule add from <tun0-interface-ip> table 11 
ip route add default via 10.3.33.20 table 11
ip route flush cache
```

for some reason won't work:

```
ip rule add oif tun0 table 11
ip route add default via 10.3.33.20 table 11
ip route flush cache
```